# sql server not handling non-ascii characters

Tags: sql-server, nvarchar

Our platform's database has stopped accepting non-ASCII characters despite it working before and despite full use of nvarchar type.  The minimal reproduction I've been able to do is this simple demonstration from a Management Studio query window:

```
DECLARE @X nvarchar(max) = 'Activbasē ਪਾਕਿਸਤਾਨ ਪੰਜਾਬ ਦਾ ਦਾਰੁਲ'
PRINT @X
SELECT @X AS X
-- Output (for table and PRINT): Activbase ???????? ????? ?? ?????
```

I'm using:

1. SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)
2. Management Studio version: v18.4 (component version 15.0.18206.0)

(both latest versions to date)

Query Options for the query window for ANSI are as follows:

- SET QUOTED_IDENTIFER = on
- SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON = on
- SET ANSI_PADDING = on
- SET ANSI_WARNINGS = on
- SET ANSI_NULLS = on
- SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS = off
- SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT = off

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how the code in your question would have ever worked without the `N` literal string prefix to denote Unicode, unless non-ASCII characters are within the collation code page.

Comment: Okay, so this was my mistake when attempting to reduce the code to a minimal example.  The reality is that I have an asp.net C# application which passes in the string to a stored procedure. I can see that string is correct when being passed in but the SP is using nvarchar across the board but it isn't working in this context.

Comment: @ChirsWalsh, [use parameterized queries](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/) and you won't have the problem, assuming the parameter data type is correct (nvarchar).

Comment: I am using parameterised queries (in fact I'm using Entity Framework) but EF had the input parameter defined as `varchar(max)` even through the SP was set to `nvarchar(max)` so I think is a case of EF's very strict model mapping remapping the string to ascii equivalent characters in the end.

Comment: @ChirsWalsh, the client parameter must be nvarchar(MAX) too. I can't speak to why EF is using `varchar` instead of `nvarchar` as it should.

Comment: If the above doesn't represent your real problem, then edit the question to one that does, @ChrisWalsh . Or ask a new question, showing why this isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a tiny mistake, you've missed the `N` prefix to show that your string is Unicode (National language character set):

```
DECLARE @X nvarchar(max) = N'Activbasē ਪਾਕਿਸਤਾਨ ਪੰਜਾਬ ਦਾ ਦਾਰੁਲ'
PRINT @X
SELECT @X AS X
```

Output:

```
Activbasē ਪਾਕਿਸਤਾਨ ਪੰਜਾਬ ਦਾ ਦਾਰੁਲ
```

Comment: I've marked this question as correct as it is correct based on the question I asked.  However the question I put forward included an (incorrect) attempt to provide a "minimal example" (which resulted in the problematic output but for a completely different reason).  My root cause was EF having an input parameter to a Stored Procedure set to `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`. Thanks